# struts2: accessing getters of action class in jsp without creating object

Tags: struts2

I am working on struts2. In my action class I have written some accessors (setter-getter). Now, suppose this action class is returning SUCCESS and in struts.xml I am open a jsp page (say abc.jsp) against the result "SUCCESS". I need the values of all getter methods written in action class without creating object of action class in my jsp (i.e abc.jsp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controller has a getPostalCode property you can do:

```
<s:textfield name="postalCode"/>
```

Which will bind the value to the controller field. Outside s: tags you can also use jsp-el; the expression ${postalCode} will do the same. Read [this documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/tag-syntax.html)